# querySelectorAll does not select the first element

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document
    .getElementById('add-a-dog-to-a-member-form')
    .addEventListener('submit',async function (event){
        event.preventDefault();
        let filter={};
        const inputs=document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text],input[type=radio]:checked');
        for (const input of inputs){
            filter[input.name]=input.value;
        }

        console.log(filter['id']);
        console.log(filter['name']);
        console.log(filter['gender']);

        event.target.reset();
    });
```

```html
<form id="add-a-dog-to-a-member-form">
  <p>Add a dog to a member.</p>
  id of the member: <input type="text"  name="id" ><br><br>
  name of the dog: <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
  gender of the dog:
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="m">
  <label for="male">Male</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="f">
  <label for="female">Female</label><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="add the dog">
</form>
```

I want to pass three values, namely id, name, and the gender of a dog's information onto the javascript code so that I can do a POST request with fetch API. I wanted to test whether all of these values are already passed onto the javascript code so I print them one by one on the console before I use them for fetch API. Now the problem is that this code only prints out the name and gender on the console, no id. So it seems that the id is not successfully passed onto javascript from the form. I don't know where it went wrong. Please help me out. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your code works, at least here in the code snippet.

Comment: yeah I know. However, in my local environment, it does not work. I use WebStorm with all the default settings. I think it's not likely going to be a problem in my local environment. So that's what got me confused @moonwave99

Comment: Well if the problem can't be reproduced I don't see how anybody can help.